# Why won't my DIV be 100% height?

Tags: css

I'm using Twitter's bootstrap "well" ID in a DIV and added my own "STYLE" in the HTML TAG but it won't seem to go 100% height?

```
style="width:65%; height:100%; display:inline-block; margin-top:60px; text-align:left;
```

Why won't it work?! I just want it 100% of the height, 65% of the width, all overflow "hidden" on the X, and all the Y overflow to have a scroll!

Comment: "100% height" of what?

Answer (score 0):

100% height only applies to parent element. If the parent tag of your div is not 100% of window space your div will not be.

Comment: Is you div an immediate child of body?